# Same bundle always loaded regardless of a accept-language header

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I am currently working on a primefaces website and I want to have it with internationalization.

I created a directory for the language bundles in:

```
src/main/resources/org/test
```

The bundle contains these files:

```
language.properties
language_en.properties
```

The faces config looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
  <application>
      <locale-config>
          <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
          <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
      </locale-config>
      <resource-bundle>
          <base-name>org.test.language</base-name>
          <var>language</var>
      </resource-bundle>
  </application>
</faces-config>
```

I tried loading the bundle in my view scoped view:

```
<f:loadBundle var="lang" basename="org.test.language"></f:loadBundle>
```

But I always get the german locale even with Accept-Language headers en_US.
What is wrong with it?

Comment: I saw that already but I was hoping that I would not need another property on my bean ... I guess I have to bite the bullet

Comment: Wow turns out if you do not explicitly attacht the iso code it screws the whole thing over

Comment: I improved your title (a lot). It only contained tags and no 'description' of the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging